# SMO database backup

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am using the following function to backup a SQL Server database using SMO.. but the backup fails... I have no idea, why does it fail... any help is appreciated.

```
Private Sub BackupSqlDatabase()

   Dim conn As New ServerConnection("MONO-PC\SQLEXPRESS") ' -- set SQL server connection given the server name, user name and password
   Dim oSQLServer As New Server(conn) '--create the SMO server object using connection

   Dim OrigBackupPath As String = oSQLServer.Information.MasterDBPath.Replace("\DATA", "C:\Backup\DB_BACKUP_NAME.BAK") ' -- set the path where backup file will be stored

   Dim bkDevItem As New BackupDeviceItem(OrigBackupPath, DeviceType.File) ' -- create SMO.Backupdevice object

   With oBackup ' Set the backup object property
      .Action = BackupActionType.Database
      .Database = "LIC.MDF"
      .Devices.Add(bkDevItem)
      .Initialize = True
      .Checksum = True
      .ContinueAfterError = True
      .Incremental = False
      .LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate
      .SqlBackup(oSQLServer) ' backup SQL database
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: backup failed..thats it...i do not have management studio installed in my pc...is that a reason for the backup failure???

Comment: Wouldn't you have to set the connection as: `Dim conn As New ServerConnection("MONO-PC\\SQLEXPRESS") `  (two backslashes) ??

Comment: Also: I don't think you should specify a **file name** for the database (`.Database = "LIC.MDF"`) - specify the **database name**, something like: `.Database = "LIC"` or whatever the database is called on your server

Answer (score 0):

What version of sql server are you using? I was using i believe 10.5 (sql server 2008 R2 service pack 1) and the SMO object was not supported.

I use sql calls instead now.

```
BACKUP DATABASE DBNAMEHERE TO DISK = 'destPath' WITH FORMAT
```

Comment: when i try it your way ...i get "Login Failed Error"

Comment: ` Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonBackup.Click
        'TextBoxBackupDirectory.Text = Application.UserAppDataPath
        'BackupSqlDatabase()
        Dim con As SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LIC;Trusted_Connection = yes")
        cmd = New SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE LIC to disk='C:\Backup\ICLS.bak'", con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("LI")
    End Sub`

Comment: You may need to give your log in user more rights on the database. To test, allow full control and then disable each right until it no longer works. Sorry I do not know the exact rights the user needs, but this should help you learn how to look into those issues in future.